# Login screen changed after using VNC

Tags: 16.04, unity, ubuntu-gnome

[image: what my screen shows]
After setting up vnc and installing gnome-tools I get this login screen! Why is this? The WiFi notifications in the corner also look different. Thanks!

Comment: You attached the image incorrectly, we can't see it.

Comment: Fixed the image

Comment: Did *"setting up vnc"* include installing XFCE components? if so, which packages did you install specifically?

Comment: Not sure what those are